# How do I fix mesh cracking when I move its bones?

Tags: bones

I downloaded a low poly model and tried rigging it, but whenever I move the bones, the model doesn't stretch any triangles and makes it look like the model is cracking.
[image]

[image]

I'm new to blender and this has been frusturating, and I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faces of the object are separate, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> in order to merge the vertices.

Comment: Thanks. the bones are still kinda funky... but the weird problem I was talking about is fixed.